# Trying to commit to cvs - No such file or directory

Tags: batch-file, command, commit, cvs

I have a bat file in which I am checking out a file from a cvs repository, running a java program to update the file, and then committing back to the repository.  I'm running into some issues with my commit command. Can anyone assist?

```
path=%path%;c:/cvsnt


cvs -d :ssh:nsbuild:xxxx@cvs1.xxxx.corpintra.net:/cvs login

cvs -d :ssh:nsbuild:xxxx@cvs1.xxxx.corpintra.net:/cvs checkout BGNMigration/JNLP/config/dev/com/xxxx/jnlp/file/xxxx.jnlp


javac UpdateVersions.java
java UpdateVersions


cvs -d /BGNMigration/JNLP/config/dev/com/xxxx/jnlp/file commit -m "Latest build" xxxx.jnlp
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\JADOYLE\Desktop\Docs\updateBat>cvs -d /BGNMigration/JNLP/config/dev/com/xxxx/jnlp/file commit -m "Latest build" xxxx.jnlp
cvs [commit aborted]: /BGNMigration/JNLP/config/dev/com/xxxx/jnlp/file/CVSROOT: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Your slashes are going the wrong way in the first line. In Windows you use `\` in paths, not `/`. First line should be `path=%path%;c:\cvsnt`.

Comment: I changed the first line to   path=%path%;c:\cvsnt`    but still receiving same output.  Why does it throw that /CVSROOT at the end of my commit path?

Answer (score 0):

I think, there is no common *-d* option for *cvs commit*.

To commit the updated file, you can try this:

```
cd  BGNMigration\JNLP\config\dev\com\xxxx\jnlp\file
cvs commit -m "Latest build" xxxx.jnlp
```